# Use typescript to extract all element type(s) from array except first

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, tuples

Say I have the type

```
type MyTypeArray = ['', 2, boolean]
```

How could I extract the type `2 | boolean` when the array could be of an unknown length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can infer all elements but first. Use `spread tuple` operator: `...`, just like in plain javascript

```js
type ExtractTail<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer _, ...infer Tail] ? Tail : never

// [2, boolean]
type MyTypeArray = ExtractTail<['', 2, boolean]>

// 2 | boolean
type Union = MyTypeArray[number]
```

Comment: @johann1301s made an update.

Comment: You can also use a similar procedure to extract just the last element of a tuple: `type LastValueOfTuple<T extends any[] | readonly any[]> = T extends [...infer Start, infer Last] ? Last : never;`

Not the question that was asked, but this is the article that appeared when I was searching for this answer.